# Email and phone number verification in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing a portal/mobile app where user need to provide email-id and phone number during registration process. I am using Congnito user pool for authentication if users opt to create user-id in the system. Cognito has features to validate phone number/ mail id for such users.

If they choose to use their facebook/linkedin id to login, there is no method in Cognito to validate email-d/phone number.

How can I validate email/phone number for federated identity users?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the question? It has mixed info, mentioning that Cognito has features to validate email and phone number and  that Cognito doesn't have such a feature.

I should mention that whatever you store in the email or phone_number attribute with Cognito is validated to be either an email or phone_number.

Comment: If I use Cognito User Pool, email and phone number gets validated. How to validate phone number, mail id if I am using COgnito Identity Pool ?

Comment: if you're looking for a client side library for validation, you can have a look at https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: Thanks. This will be useful.  Additionally I wanted to have a feature of sending OTP via SMS for phone number and validation code via mail for mail verification.

Comment: @Aman for sending the OTP you need to use SNS. make all the relevant configuration in the SNS service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Identity Provider (Google, Facebook, Cognito User Pool, etc.) you would use the Provider's SDK functions to verify email or mobile, etc.

Think of it this way. Cognito Federated Identities is management interface supporting a number of Identity Providers. Cognito User Pools, LinkedIn, etc are the Identity Providers that provide a token that Cognito Federated Identities accepts to identify users. Cognito Federated Identities does not manage individual users.

Use the Facebook / LinkedIn SDK to manage their users.